# Transaction in Entity Framwork- save the record and rollback which fails

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

I have written 3 statements within a transation:

- first for insert
- second for update
- third for delete

If first and second execute succesfully, and the third one fails due to some error, then I want to rollback the only third statement, and the first two should be saved.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
  using (var context = new YourContext()) 
                { 
                    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
                    { 
                        try 
                        { 
                          //first for insert
                           //second for update

                            dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
                        } 
                        catch (Exception) 
                        { 
                            dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
                        } 
                    } 
         using (var dbContextTransaction1 = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
                    { 
                        try 
                        { 
                          //third for delete

                            dbContextTransaction1.Commit(); 
                        } 
                        catch (Exception) 
                        { 
                            dbContextTransaction1.Rollback(); 
                        } 
                    } 

                }
```

}